# How to join a column of values with comma then space?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm trying to loop through an array that I got from `preg_match_all` result in order to create one string from all results.

Array looks like this:

```
print_r($matches[0]);


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8147
            [1] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8204
            [1] => 20
        )

)
```

And my code:

```
$found = count($matches[0]);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $found; $i++) {
    $string = $matches[0][$i];
}
```

I would like to get result of `$string` like this: `8147, 8204`.

How I can append `$matches[0][0]` to `$matches[0][1]` etc. in string variable using loop?

Comment: $string .= $matches[0][$i] . ",";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With php5.5 and more you can use `array_column` + `implode`:

```
echo implode(', ', array_column($matches, 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this some ting like that

```
$string = "";
foreach($matches[0] as $value) {
    $string .= $value[0].", ";
}
$string = rtrim(", ",$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code. Loop through array and get values

```
$arr =Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            0 => 8147,
            1 => 3
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            0 => 8204,
            1 => 20
        )

);
$match_array = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
{
    $match_array[] = $value[0];
}
$str =  implode(",",$match_array);
echo $str;
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/i7arU)

OR simply use array_column to get specific column as array then use implode

```
$arr =Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            0 => 8147,
            1 => 3
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            0 => 8204,
            1 => 20
        )

);
$match_array = array_column($arr,0);

$str =  implode(",",$match_array);
echo $str;
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/reYeF)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_column`, no need to loop over the array

```
$result = join(',', array_column($arr, 0));
```